# Undefined index: in PHP codeigniter while sending variable

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My controller:

```
public function thread($page = 'empty')
{

    $data['user_id'] = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
    $data['username'] = $this->tank_auth->get_username();
    //User data variable grab
    //default template load data
    $data['thread'] = $this->thread_model->get_thread($page);
    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
    $data['replies'] = $this->thread_model->get_reply($data['thread']['thread_id']);
    $this->thread_model->view_increment($data);
    $this->load->view('templates/head', $data);
    $this->load->view('main/wrapper-start', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/leftbar', $data);
    $this->load->view('main/thread', $data);
    $this->load->view('main/wrapper-end', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

}
```

The error appears on the `$data['replies']` line:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: thread_id
>
> Filename: controllers/main.php
>
> Line Number: 40

Here is my model code that replies refers to: `$this->thread_model->get_reply`

```
public function get_reply($thread_id)
{

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT r.reply_id FROM reply_thread rt
    INNER JOIN replies r
    ON rt.reply_id = r.reply_id
    WHERE thread_id = ". $thread_id);
    $replies = $query->result_array();
    $replyarray = array();
    foreach ($replies as $reply)
    {
        $id = $reply['reply_id'];
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM replies WHERE reply_id='$id'");
        $thisRow = $query->row_array();
        $replyarray[] = $thisRow;
    }

    return $replyarray;
}
```

Any ideas why this error is popping up?  Other than the error, the page loads perfectly fine...all the info is in tact and available through the query.

here is my get_thread model

```
public function get_thread($page)
{
    $slug = $page;
    $query = $this->db->get_where('thread', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

using a `print_r($data['thread']);` I get this array:

```
Array ( [thread_id] => 233 [owner_id] => 8 [subject] => Repercussions of D3 addiction [body] => 1. signs of unhygienic practices 2.become irritable when forced to stop playing 3. carpal tunnel 4. loss of interest in pursuing a significant other 5. sleep deprivation 6. malnutrition There's nothing positive about this. [timestamp] => 2012-05-08 19:03:02 [replystamp] => 2012-05-09 12:38:32 [last_post_id] => 3 [slug] => 233-repercussions-of-d3-addiction [replies_num] => 2 [views] => 21 )
```

Comment: @Wesley edited, and added.  The one thing I noticed is that this is the only function in my model that uses active record for query.

Comment: Hmm... so what happens when you do this: `exit(print_r($data['thread']['thread_id']))`? NULL? I can say though that you *should* check first to make sure you got a result before assuming the index `thread_id` is populated. I forget if `row_array()` returns FALSE or an empty array on failure, either way you should check, but since you said you are able to get all the `$replies`, it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @wesley Hmm. I'll expand to the best of my knowledge.  Long ago, this was giving me a problem, so i BELIEVE i changed an error reporting function within the php.ini.  It stopped showing up on the actual page, though it is still showing up in Firebug, and is quite annoying :X.  Would it have something to do with the changes made to the php.ini?

Comment: No chance - It's just something simple. The error reporting? Maybe, just set it to E_ALL right at the top of your model file for now `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. So what happened when you ran `exit(print_r($data['thread']['thread_id']))`?

Comment: @wesley running `exit(print_r($data['thread']['thread_id']))` printed 2341.  a normal print_r will print 234

Comment: Oops yeah because exit prints the print_r as 1. So I don't get how you can possibly have an undefined index message if the index obviously exists and has a value. It just doesn't make sense. Add this to the previous line (right before `$data['replies'] = `) and tell me if you hit the error: `isset($data['thread']['thread_id']) OR show_error('Failed to find the thread ID.');`

Comment: `An Error Was Encountered Failed to find the thread ID.`

Comment: So that error appears *every* time now? I'm out of ideas - sorry, best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try this:

```
$threadinfo = $this->thread_model->get_thread($page);
$data['thread'] = $threadinfo;
$data['replies'] = $this->thread_model->get_reply($threadinfo->thread_id);
```